# Deserializing byte stream to objects

Tags: python, object, serialization, stream, byte

I am building a python project that receives bytes from a serial port. The bytes are responses to commands sent (also via serial port). The responses have no identifying marks, i.e. from the bytes alone, I don't know which command response this is. The decoder would of course need to know in advance which command this is a response to.

I would like to have the incoming byte sequence represented as a nested object, indicating the frame, header, payload, decoded payload, etc. I would much prefer to push 1 byte at a time to the decoder and have it call a callback once it has received enough bytes for a full object (or errorCallback if there are errors or timeout).

The actual frame has a start byte and an end byte. It has a header with a few bytes (some id, command status (basically ok/fail)), one is a data length byte. This is followed by the data which is followed by a checksum (single byte). The data is the response to the command.

The response is predictable in that the previous bytes decide what the coming bytes mean.

Example response:

aa:00:0c:00:01:00:00:d3:8d:d4:5c:50:01:04:e0:6e:bb

Broken down:

```
aa: start frame
    00: id
    0c: data length (incl status): 12 bytes
    00: command status (byte 1)
        01: 1 data frame (byte 2)
            00:00: flags of first data frame (byte 3-4)
            d3:8d:d4:5c:50:01:04:e0: first data (aa and bb could be in it) (byte 5-12)
    6e: checksum (includes all bytes except start, checksum, end bytes)
bb: end frame
```

This being serial port communication, bytes may be lost (and extra produced) and I expect to use timeout to handle resets (no responses are expected without first a command being sent).

I really would like an object oriented approach where the decoder would produce an object that when serialized, would produce the same byte sequence again. I am using python 2.7, but really any object oriented language would do (as long as I could convert it to python).

I am just not sure how to structure the decoder to make it neat looking. I am looking for a full solution, just something that would get me going in the right direction (right direction being somewhat subjective here).

Comment: You're more likely to get a positive response to your question if you post some code. Don't worry if it's not neat, or doesn't use any advanced tricks. Not only does posting some code show that you've made an honest attempt to solve your problem yourself, a slab of code is a very helpful way to show exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Do you mean you simply wish to parse incoming fixed-length responses into objects (with attributes) that can be converted back to bytes?

Comment: I did have some code but it was horrible and actually didn't work properly. Also, it did not fulfill my desire to make it modular. The answer below by TisteAndii is actually better than what I had.

Answer (score 2):

I don't completely understand what you want to do but if you want to receive fixed-length responses from some device and make them attributes of some object, would something like this be okay?:

```
START_FRAME = 0xAA
END_FRAME = 0xBB
TIMEOUT = 2

class Response:
def __init__(self, response):
    if (len(response) - 6) % 11 == 0 and response[0] == START_FRAME and response[-1] == END_FRAME:  # verify that its a valid response
        self.header = {}   # build header
        self.header['id'] = response[1]
        self.header['length'] = response[2]
        self.header['status'] = response[3]
        self.r_checksum = response[-2]  # get checksum from response
        self.checksum = self.header['id'] ^ self.header['length'] ^ self.header['status']   # verify the checksum
        self.payload = response[4:-2] # get raw payload slice
        self.decode(self.payload)  # parse payload
        if self.r_checksum == self.checksum: # final check
            self.parsed = True
        else:
            self.parsed = False
    else:  # if response didnt follow the pattern
        self.parsed = False
def decode(self, packet):  # decode payload
    self.frm_count = packet[0]   # get number of data frames
    self.checksum ^= self.frm_count  
    self.decoded = []   # hold decoded payload
    frames = packet[1:]
    for c in range(self.frm_count):  # iterate through data frames
        flags = frames[(c*10):(c*10 + 2)]
        for f in flags:
            self.checksum ^= f
        data = frames[(c*10 + 2):(c+1)*10]
        for d in data:
            self.checksum ^= d
        self.decoded.append({'frame': c+1, 'flags': flags, 'data':data})
def serialize():  # reconstruct response
    res = bytearray()
    res.append(START_FRAME)
    res.extend([self.header['id'], self.header['length'], self.header['status']])
    res.extend(self.payload)
    res.extend([self.checksum, END_FRAME])
    return res

response = bytearray()
ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600)   # timeout is 2 seconds
last_read = time.clock()
while time.clock() -  last_read < TIMEOUT:
    while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
        response.append(ser.read())
        last_read = time.clock()
decoded_res = Response(response)
if decoded_res.parsed:
    # do stuff
else:
    print('Invalid response!')
```

This code assumes there may be more than one data frame, with the data frames immediately preceded by a byte indicating the number of data frames.
Parsing a packet is fast compared to the time taken for serial comms (even at 115200 baud). The whole thing is roughly O(n), i think.

Comment: You assumption is correct for the shown response. I do get various different responses that have to be decoded in each their own way, depending on the command sent. Your code can be expanded to take that into account, by adding extra decode methods (one for each command; properly ). I think your suggestion is good enough for me to build on, even though the class need a full frame to begin decoding. I had hoped for a more stream oriented approach. Using timeouts to break the byte stream into packets may turn out to be unreliable (and slow-ish). I hope this wont be an issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Perhaps u could expand by what u mean by stream-oriented? Dont u need a frame to be complete before u make sense of it, since the frame may turn out to be incomplete/invalid? You could reduce the timeout period (if your baud rate is high enough) and even get rid of the time.sleep() instead using time.clock() or so to measure intervals instead of wasting a sec doing nothing. Let me edit the code

Comment: My worry is mostly if the responses come back-to-back, i.e. the packets cannot be split by looking at just the timeout (as there would be none). But I think I can afford a small delay after each response before sending a new request to the device. I need to send as many requests (and get as many replies) as fast as possible. A timeout of 1-2 characters time should be affordable. By stream-oriented I think of a way to sending an endless stream bytes to a class and have it call a callback once it has a full packet. Further bytes would result in more callbacks. Your code is a good starting point.